# Unable to use Keyboard {Xamarin.Forms}

Tags: c#, keyboard, xamarin, cross-platform

When using an Entry in a custom ViewCell with keyboard set to non default value
(for example Numeric) - if you focus an entry, default text keyboard is shown
then hidden instantly. When you focus it second time, numeric keyboard is shown
as intended.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  Have you filed a bug for this with Xamarin?

Comment: Solution is in main activity add :
 [Activity(Label = "blablabla.bla", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize 
  | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
  WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan)]

Comment: Having similar problem, but in my case I do not see any keyboard showing up. Even with the proposed solution by @Ibrahim

Comment: @donttellya Testing :                                                                                      Entry Quantity = new Entry ();                                                  Quantity.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;

Comment: @Ibrahim I tried that (also in a little test program on the emulator and real device), but the keyboard does not show up. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In Main Activity add:

```
[Activity(Label = "Bla bLa", MainLauncher = true,Theme = "@style/MyTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize 
    | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    WindowSoftInputMode = Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan)]
```